# A binomial identité

Tags: combinations, binomial-coefficients, binomial-theorem

I tried to solve this exercise but i failed. If anyone can give me hint or solution i would be grateful.

Let $(n,p,q)\in\mathbb{N}^{3}$ such that $n\leq p$ and $n\leq q$. Show that:$$\sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{p}{k}\binom{q}{n-k}=\binom{p+q}{n}.$$

Comment: Have you ever heard of a "story proof" before? Imagine a group of $p+q$ coins that contains $p$ pennies and $q$ quarters. We want to sample $n$ of these $p+q$ coins without replacement... do you see where I'm going with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since
$$ (1+x)^p(1+x)^q=(1+x)^{p+q} $$
or
$$ \sum_{k=0}^p\binom{p}{k}x^k\sum_{i=0}^q\binom{q}{i}x^i=\sum_{i=0}^{p+q}\binom{p+q}{i}x^i $$
comparing the coefficients of $x^n$ for both sides, you will have
$$\sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{p}{k}\binom{q}{n-k}=\binom{p+q}{n}.$$

Comment: Thank you very much.